# How to set new Sequence of the index while creating a new row in a table?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In the following example below, I create a new table with a custom column named label, which is, literally, the index of the `gridRow` array of objects.

I faced a problem while trying to create a new row which is inserted before the last element, (before last `object` in my case).

And there came the problem with not getting in the sequence of the label/index.

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-new-row-389jjo?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
function App() {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = React.useState(null);

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  };

  const defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "label",
      field: "label"
    },
    {
      headerName: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    { headerName: "stop", field: "stop" },
    {
      headerName: "duration",
      field: "duration"
    }
  ];
  const rowData = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        name: "John",
        stop: 10,
        duration: 5
      },
      {
        name: "David",
        stop: 15,
        duration: 8
      },
      {
        name: "Dan",
        stop: 20,
        duration: 6
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const rowDataWithIndex = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      rowData &&
      rowData.map((row, index) => ({
        ...row,
        label: index
      }))
    );
  }, [rowData]);

  const addNewRow = () => {
    gridApi.applyTransaction({
      add: [{ label: rowDataWithIndex[rowDataWithIndex.length - 2].label + 1 }],
      addIndex: rowDataWithIndex.length - 1
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addNewRow}>New Row</button>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine">
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            rowData={rowDataWithIndex}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            domLayout={"autoHeight"}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to note that the following answer may not be the best approach for your use case, it will depend on your requirements and what you're trying to achieve.

I can see that `rowData` is passed to `rowDataWithIndex` to add the labels, and that they are both memoised. The issue here is that calling `gridApi.applyTransaction()` will update the data inside the grid but it will not change the `rowData` variable (it's only computed once due to the `[]` dependency) hence the memoised callback will not be recomputed.

So to fix this, I changed `rowData` to be a state variable instead and to add a new row, I call `setRowData()`:

```
  const addNewRow = () => {
    setRowData([
      ...rowData,
      { label: rowDataWithIndex[rowDataWithIndex.length - 1].label + 1 }
    ]);
  };
```

This will ensure that `rowDataWithIndex` is recomputed.

See this implemented in the following [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-new-row-forked-k4ujnf?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your approach looks good, but there is something that still is not fixed. The new created row should be one before the last element in the array, but not the last one.
That's why I needed  "addIndex: rowDataWithIndex.length - 1"  from ag grid.

Comment: updated the sample to add the new item before the last element